# Android Studio: Passing data from android to php

Tags: android

I am working on beacon project to find out bluetooth's uuid,address,name,major,minor,rssi etc..I am getting all those values..But the problem is I have to push these data to php myadmin server, i have used volley library for database and php files for server..I will post my code of the activity and php files as well...Please find out the solution for this.... Thanks in advance..

BluetoothActivity.java

```
private ListView listview;
private static final String LOG_TAG = "MainActivity";
private String url = "http://localhost/blue/testing.php";
private BluetoothManager btManager;
private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
private Handler scanHandler = new Handler();
private int scan_interval_ms = 5000;
private boolean isScanning = false;
private ArrayAdapter adapter;
private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // init BLE

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter
            (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    btManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    btAdapter = btManager.getAdapter();
    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    scanHandler.post(scanRunnable);
    //new scanHandler(getApplicationContext(),getMainLooper());
}

private void scanHandler(Context applicationContext, Looper mainLooper) {
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// public usage
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

private Runnable scanRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        if (isScanning) {
            if (btAdapter != null) {
                btAdapter.stopLeScan(leScanCallback);
            }
        } else {
            if (btAdapter != null) {
                btAdapter.startLeScan(leScanCallback);
            }
        }

        isScanning = !isScanning;

        scanHandler.postDelayed(this, scan_interval_ms);
    }
};

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Inner classes
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
int rssi1,major1,minor1;
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback leScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, final byte[] scanRecord) {
        /* scanHandler.getLooper();*/
        int startByte = 2;
        rssi1=rssi;
        boolean patternFound = false;
        while (startByte <= 5) {
            if (((int) scanRecord[startByte + 2] & 0xff) == 0x02 && //Identifies an iBeacon
                    ((int) scanRecord[startByte + 3] & 0xff) == 0x15) { //Identifies correct data length
                patternFound = true;
                break;
            }
            startByte++;
        }

        if (patternFound) {
            //Convert to hex String
            byte[] uuidBytes = new byte[16];
            System.arraycopy(scanRecord, startByte + 4, uuidBytes, 0, 16);
            String hexString = bytesToHex(uuidBytes);

            //UUID detection
            final String uuid = hexString.substring(0, 8) + "-" +
                    hexString.substring(8, 12) + "-" +
                    hexString.substring(12, 16) + "-" +
                    hexString.substring(16, 20) + "-" +
                    hexString.substring(20, 32);

            // major
            final int major = (scanRecord[startByte + 20] & 0xff) * 0x100 + (scanRecord[startByte + 21] & 0xff);
            major1=major;
            // minor
            final int minor = (scanRecord[startByte + 22] & 0xff) * 0x100 + (scanRecord[startByte + 23] & 0xff);
            minor1=minor;
            adapter.add("Name:  "+ device.getName() + "\n" + "BluetoothAddress: "+ device.getAddress()+"\n" +"UUID:"+ uuid +"\n" + "MajorKey: "+ major +"\n" +"MinorKey: "+ minor + "\n"+ "RSSI:  "+ rssi);

            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "UUID: " + uuid +"\n"+ "nmajor: " + major + "\n"+"nminor" + minor+"\n" +"rssi1" + rssi +"\n"+device.getAddress()+"\n"+device.getName());

            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "dfdsfsd"+response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i("My success",""+response);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "my error :"+error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.i("My error",""+error);
                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("bluetoothname",device.getName());
                    map.put("bluetoothaddress",device.getAddress());
                    map.put("bluetoothUUID",uuid);
                    map.put("bluetoothMajorKey",String.valueOf(major1));
                    map.put("bluetoothMinorKey",String.valueOf(minor1));
                    map.put("bluetoothrssi",String.valueOf(rssi1));


                    return map;
                }
            };
        }

    }
};

/**
 * bytesToHex method
 */
static final char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();

private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
        int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}
```

}

Comment: You can't call apis hosted on localhost by saying localhost in url. Either use the ip or host your api somewhere on server

Comment: Where is your server hosted? If it is on a local PC, is the phone/emulator in the same network with the PC?

Comment: yes the phone and the server are in the same network

Comment: I can see in the code that you are printing error and success logs, what error do you get? Is your request getting executed at least because I can't see where you execute the request. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
private String url = "http://localhost/blue/testing.php";
```

To,

```
private String url = "http://your_ip_address/blue/testing.php";
```

Something like: 50.65.76.198

```
Ex: private String url = "http://50.65.76.198/blue/testing.php";
```

Hopefully it should work.

Comment: it is not working i tried with both IP address and localhost

Comment: @PoojaNagaraj Check if you've added a Internet Permission in your Manifest.

Comment: @PoojaNagaraj Did you check whether your URL is correct like in POSTMAN ? is it working fine there? What response you are getting in Androdi

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation.
If you run your php server on a pc, you can find your pc's ip address with ifconfig. I usually find it as eg 192.168.43.1, so when I run android in simulator, I use URL as
http://192.168.43.1/xxx.php
Even though simulator runs on same pc, "localhost" will not work.
This also works when I test android app with phone, as long as they are in same network.

Comment: I run the application on android phone and they are on the same network

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
private String url = "http://localhost/blue/testing.php";
```

To:

```
private String url = "http://ip/blue/testing.php";
```

Get your ip address using ipconfig command in command prompt. See the image for clarification.

[image: Ip Address]

If you have wifi and your computer and real device (mobile) is connected to the same wifi you can use [**NGROK**](https://ngrok.com/download) software tool to run and debug your app in your real device.

Run the ngrok.exe and type **ngrok http 80**,  it will give you an address like the below image.

[image: Click]

Just use the url in your app where you use your ip address. 
It is best to use. just use the forwarding address.

Comment: Thank you so much.I wll try with this

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add port on which you server running 
like 8080 along with ip address as below

```
private String url = "http://your_ip_address:port/blue/testing.php";
```

Something like: 50.65.76.198:8080

Ex: `private String url = "http://50.65.76.198:8080/blue/testing.php";`